# what happens if the script which calls preloaded content doesn't find it

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have this:

index.css

```
.div-class {
    background-image: url('image-1.jpeg');
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="preload" as="image" href="image-1.jpeg" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"  />    
    <div class="div-class">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**I am using slow network of chrome. index.css is 400B and image-1.jpeg is 280kb.**

Now, If you look at the index.html code, it turns out that downloading image-1.jpeg happens because of the preload. It's gonna take almost 8 seconds. Also, in parallel, index.css started downloading, but as it's 400B, it downloaded immediatelly. So we got index.css already downloaded and image-1.jpeg of preloading is still being downloaded. Time to run index.css. in there, we got image-1.jpeg including, so my question is the following:

browser already had started downloading image-1.jpeg. when it reached `background-image: url('image-1.jpeg');`, what does it do exactly? of course, it can't take the image from cache as preload hasn't finished and it didn't put the image in HTTP cache. So browser figured out that downloading image-1.jpeg is already happening and didn't do anything at all? waited the download and just put the image in src?